# Using a variable when iterating over range in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have this task :

```yaml
---
- name: Deploy & Register the Gitlab runners
  command: >
    docker run
    --name runner{{item}}
    -d
    -e CI_SERVER_URL="{{CI_SERVER_URL}}"
    -e REGISTRATION_TOKEN="{{REGISTRATION_TOKEN}}"
    -e DOCKER_PRIVILEGED=true
    -e REGISTER_LOCKED=false
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    --restart=always
    flakm/gitlab-runner-auto-register:latest
  with_items:
    - [ 1 , 2 ]
```

which works. But I would like to be able to customise the number of the runners.

So, I would like something like this

```yaml
  with_items:
    - [ 1 , {{ NUMBER_ΟF_RUNNERS }} ]
```

but this does not work.

I have read [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) from the Ansible docs, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [range](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence). For example

```
  loop: "{{ range(1, NUMBER_ΟF_RUNNERS + 1)|list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, I found something that works here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences

Comment: You reference Ansible 2.4. See [Migrating from with_X to loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) in Ansible 2.5.

Comment: Thanks , will do!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

`with_sequence: count={{NUMBER_OF_RUNNERS}}`

here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences